How to compute a pooled standard error
I am comparing $m$ methods across $d$ datasets. Through my experiments I have obtained the mean, the standard deviation, and the standard error for all methods and all datasets, hence I have the means
$$
\bar x_{1,1}, \dots, \bar x_{1, m},
\\
\vdots
\\
\bar x_{d,1}, \dots, \bar x_{d, m},
$$
and the standard errors
$$
\hat s_{1,1}, \dots, \hat s_{1, m},
\\
\vdots
\\
\hat s_{d,1}, \dots, \hat s_{d, m}.
$$
I want to make a statement per method across all datasets, i.e., I would like to pool both of these quantities. So I am pretty sure I can compute the mean per method $k$ as
$$
\bar X_k = \frac 1 d \sum_{i=1}^d \bar x_{i, k}
$$
but what should I do about the standard errors? Is it okay to combine them in a similar fashion, i.e.,
$$
\hat S_k = \sqrt{\frac 1 d} \; \sum_{i = 1}^d \hat s_{i, k},
$$
or do I need to approach this differently?

I would recommend averaging the variance instead of the standard deviation.
$$\hat{S}_k = \sqrt{\frac{1}{d} \sum_{i=1}^d s^2_{i,k}}$$
